# Error on Apache Ignite Web Console

Tags: datagrid, ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

When I start Ignite web agent and open web console GUI I am getting following error continuously.

Failed to collect configuration for: AB69E0D4Failed to handle request: [req=EXE, taskName=org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.compute.VisorGatewayTask, params=[AB69E0D4-B2F6-4D0F-B736-7290562BD2B3, org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheConfigurationCollectorTask, org.apache.ignite.internal.visor.cache.VisorCacheConfigurationCollectorTaskArg, java.util.Collection, org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteUuid, 2a9bbfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d;97dfb0d7d51-790da152-19cd-42bb-ba76-5a32cc8273fa;368bbfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d;bb0dbfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d;8c0dbfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d;bab6bfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d;e48bbfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d;f7dfb0d7d51-790da152-19cd-42bb-ba76-5a32cc8273fa;5a0dbfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d;858bbfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d;dbb6bfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d;1bb6bfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d;7bb6bfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d;448bbfc7d51-57f09302-be06-41e7-99b2-fb61b5d5604d], err=javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder$ClassFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory

Comment: Did you try anything? Researched? BTW, you didn't even ask a question, technically.

Answer (score 3):

It's a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5781

It's already fixed in master and will end up in 2.2.